# Wait for application window loading

Tags: c#, window, loading

Hi I am working with an automatisation of certain app like obs. What I am trying to do is launch obs and wait for it to load its window is there a way to check if the window has shown ?

Tried this but the process start instantly it does not take in concideration if the app has shown its window

```
Process[] obs = Process.GetProcessesByName("obs64");
while (obs.Count() == 0 && firefox.Count() == 0){
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    obs = Process.GetProcessesByName("obs64");
}
```

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(1000);` this is hatred, please don't do this, messages wont be pumped. Doing this will stop all execution and more than likely your issue here. If you want a delay, maybe something like: `await Task.Delay(1000);` and your caller needs to be marked `async`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way by using the MainWindowHandle

```
Process obsProcess = Process.Start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\obs-studio\\bin\\64bit\\OBS.exe");
while (obsProcess.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero) Thread.Sleep(1000);
```